# Spark-Submit failing in cluster mode when passing files using --files

Tags: apache-spark, spark-submit

I have a Java-spark code that reads certain properties files. These properties are being passed with `spark-submit` like:

```
spark-submit 
--master yarn \
--deploy-mode cluster \
--files /home/aiman/SalesforceConn.properties,/home/aiman/columnMapping.prop,/home/aiman/sourceTableColumns.prop \
--class com.sfdc.SaleforceReader \
--verbose \
--jars /home/ebdpbuss/aiman/Salesforce/ojdbc-7.jar /home/aiman/spark-salesforce-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar SalesforceConn.properties columnMapping.prop sourceTableColumns.prop
```

The code that I have written is:

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().master("yarn").config("spark.submit.deployMode","cluster").getOrCreate();
JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(spark.sparkContext());
Configuration config = jsc.hadoopConfiguration();
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(config);

//args[] is the file names that is passed as arguments.
String connDetailsFile = args[0];
String mapFile = args[1];
String sourceColumnsFile = args[2];

String connFile = SparkFiles.get(connDetailsFile);
String mappingFile = SparkFiles.get(mapFile);
String srcColsFile = SparkFiles.get(sourceColumnsFile);

Properties prop = loadProperties(fs,connFile);
Properties mappings = loadProperties(fs,mappingFile);
Properties srcColProp = loadProperties(fs,srcColsFile);
```

The `loadProperties()` method I used above:

```
private static Properties loadProperties(FileSystem fs, String path)
{
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    FSDataInputStream is = null;
    try{
        is = fs.open(new Path(path));
        prop.load(is);
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }

    return prop;        
}
```

And its giving me exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Application application_1550650871366_125913 finished with failed status
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.run(Client.scala:1187)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$.main(Client.scala:1233)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.main(Client.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:782)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:119)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
19/03/01 14:34:00 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
```

Comment: The error message is not complete @aiman

Answer (score 0):

When you pass the path to files using --files they are stored in the local directory (temporary) for each executor. So if the file names do not change then you can just use them as follows instead of using the full path provided in arguments.

```
String connDetailsFile = "SalesforceConn.properties";
String mapFile = "columnMapping.prop";
String sourceColumnsFile = "sourceTableColumns.prop";
```

If the file names do change each time then you have to strip off the path to the file and just use the file name. This is because spark doesn't recognize that as a path but considers the whole string to be a file name. 
For example, **/home/aiman/SalesforceConn.properties** will be considered as a file name and spark will give you an exception saying it can't find a file with name **/home/aiman/SalesforceConn.properties**

So your code should be something like this.

```
String connDetailsFile = args[0].split("/").last
String mapFile = args[1].split("/").last
String sourceColumnsFile = args[2].split("/").last
```

Comment: I am using the files names only in the argumants: `/home/aiman/spark-salesforce-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar SalesforceConn.properties columnMapping.prop sourceTableColumns.prop`.

Comment: But these filenames are provided as arguments to the jar. So the args[0], args[1],args[2] you are using to read will have the path to files that you are providing in --files option. So you'll have to extract just the filenames from these paths and then use it to read the file. Also if you could post the exact error you're seeing that would give more info to debug.

Comment: No. The arguments passed are nothing but strings...that contains just a name...not the whole path, i.e. `SalesforceConn.properties` ..a string is a file name only. Similarly for other 2 arguments.

Comment: Then there is some other problem. Could you post the complete error message ? The exception message you have in your question doesn't give any info to debug.